# What is the difference in methods to call upon a JSON object by key name?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I tried my best to think of a name of this question, I'll change it if I can get some terminology to help

Best way I can describe it is this

```
obj1 = {
    "a":{"var":1},
    "b":{"var":2},
    "c":{"var":3}
}

// What's the difference between
resulta = obj1['a']['var']

// and...
resultb = obj1.a.var
```

So, what's the difference between using [''] and . ?

I realize you can only use . to run functions, but is that the only difference?

Is one method faster than the other? (even a little?)

Comment: You can call functions using array accessors: `var obj = {someFunc: function() { console.log('hi'); }};` - `obj['someFunc']();` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method with square brackets is handy if you're dynamically building your object's property keys:

```
var myDynamicKey = "a";
var result = obj[myDynamicKey]["var"];
var result = obj["someOtherKey_" + myDynamicKey]["var"];
```

The second one is definitely preferred if you know what the properties are in advance.

Note you can mix and match them:

```
var result = obj[myDynamicKey].var;
```

I'd be willing to bet that accessing properties using dot notation is faster, but I have no actual data to support that.

Comment: Since `var` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, the last bit will probably not work with every interpreter.

Comment: I was just trying to mimic the OP's object structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [''] then you can pass the name of the key in as a dynamic variable... which can change at run time. If you use the .key.key method, then you have to know at build time what the keys are.

Example:

```
var keys = ['name','phone','email'];
var object = {"name": ,"phone": , "email"};
function updateKeys(name,phone,email){
    for(var i = 0; i < keys; i++){
        object[keys[i]] = arguments[i]
    }
}
```

vs

```
function updateKeys(name, phone, email){
    object.name = name; 
    object.phone = phone;
    object.email = email
}
```

The [''] way is much more flexible and allows for more code resuse. Most libraries will use this, or some homegrown replacement of the [''] way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

There are various websites with information about this.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html
or
[http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29)
or
[http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+(Reaching+into+Objects)](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29)

The first I would call `dot notation` which can be used to access Methods and Properties of an object, and the 2nd is Associative Array.